# How to get HIE to detect packages installed via stack for scripts

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, haskell-ide-engine

I'm just getting started with learning how to use haskell for scripting, and I've got something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-14.13 script
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Turtle

main :: IO ()
main = echo "hello"
```

When I run this with `stack script.hs`, it auto-magically installs turtle and prints "hello". However, my editor gives me this error on the import line:

```
[ghcmod] [E] Could not find module ‘Turtle’
```

This makes some sense to me because the hie-wrapper I installed (from source, if it matters), isn't aware of where stack has installed the turtle package.

The way I have my HIE hooked up is like so, using coc.nvim:

```
  "languageserver": {
        "haskell": {
            "command": "hie-wrapper",
            "rootPatterns": [
                ".stack.yaml",
                "cabal.config",
                "package.yaml"
            ],
            "filetypes": [
                "hs",
                "lhs",
                "haskell"
            ],
            "initializationOptions": {
                "languageServerHaskell": {
                }
            },
        }
  },
```

Are there some flags or something I can pass to hie-wrapper to get it to play nicely with Haskell scripts, ie. detect packages? Would greatly appreciate any answer that makes it a bit more clear how this stuff fits together, ghc/hie/hie-wrapper/stack/cabal are a big black box to me currently, making this hard to debug.

Comment: AFAIK unfortunately there is no special direct support for scripts in hie, but it could be a improvement so consider open an issue in the project: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine/issues/new

Comment: hie itself uses a [script with another configuration](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine/blob/master/install.hs), the code executed by the script is in its own [folder](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine/tree/master/install) and hie is able to handle it if you open the ìnstall` folder in your editor

Comment: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine/issues/1453

Comment: Have you tried a `hie.yaml` file? https://github.com/mpickering/hie-bios/blob/master/README.md This file can be generated with: https://github.com/Avi-D-coder/implicit-hie